# Is there anyway to render a website and share it without hosting it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a repl.it website for a project. The problem is my teacher requires the website NOT to be published, which means I can't use repl.it to host it.

I am wondering if there is any way to make a copy of the website that can be viewed by Google Chrome without connecting to a host. I have all the HTML,CSS, and JS files. Also, it would be optimal if the teacher didn't have to download any additional software. My Google searches have given me suggestions requiring software, which is why I am asking here.

Comment: If the teacher has specific rules about how to hand in your homework....you should probably consult with them to find out how it should be handed in, rather than asking complete strangers for ideas which the teacher might or might not accept.

Comment: If it doesn't require a server (database, server language) you can save it on your PC and view it in a browser, but to share it, you'd just have to share all the files.

Comment: @mason Thank you for bringing that up. I have already spoken to her and we have a way to view the website, but it is suboptimal (I have to share my screen). I want to know if there is another way in the future.

Comment: @user1599011 I didn't think of that! I am not using server side, so I think that should work. Thanks so much!

Comment: For HTML/CSS/JS you can save all your file in a local folder  but you need to create relative reference to you local file (ex. for link a css you need a path like "/css/style.css")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create your files with the right extension in a folder in your computer. You might start with your índex.html and If you set the correct local paths to link each html page, your css, js files and assets when you open your índex.html with chrome it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try making a folder in a place where you can share files (Google Drive, Microsoft OneDrive, etc.), and put all your HTML, CSS, and JS files there. You can then share that folder with your teacher, and you can ask your teacher to compile those files in some HTML compiler.